Why is my usage of EF Core leading to duplicate id values?
I'm using EF Core (9.0.0) as an application/project file with a SQLite database. I have an issue where SaveChanges throws an exception because of duplicate id values.
Here are the steps:

Create a single object in my project, the object is initialized with ID = 0
Create a DbContext and add the object to the DbContext
Call SaveChanges(), and the object now has ID = 1
If I use SQLite DB Browser, I see that the object is stored with ID = 1
Close the application, and relaunch
Load the project file, and the object is loaded into the application with ID = 1 from the database
Create a new object, which is initialized with ID = 0
Create a new DbContext, and add both the original object (ID = 1) and the new object (ID = 0)
Call SaveChanges()

At this point, I get an exception:

SqliteException: SQLite Error 19: 'UNIQUE constraint failed: [Class].Id'.

The objects experiencing this issue have the ID property defined like this:
public int Id { get; set; }

How can I refactor my application to avoid this ID conflict? I'm not certain how the responsibility for managing and assigning ID values works. I thought I could basically just ignore the ID fields and set up the relationships, allowing EF to handle the values of the ID fields entirely, but it appears I've missed something.

Here is the code for creating one of the tables where I was having this issue:
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "LayoutElements",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
            .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
        DrawingDataId = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: true),
        ElementType = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
        X = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
        Y = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
        BaseWidth = table.Column<double>(type: "REAL", nullable: false),
        BaseHeight = table.Column<double>(type: "REAL", nullable: false),
        Width = table.Column<double>(type: "REAL", nullable: false),
        Height = table.Column<double>(type: "REAL", nullable: false),
        ScaleX = table.Column<double>(type: "REAL", nullable: false),
        ScaleY = table.Column<double>(type: "REAL", nullable: false),
        Discriminator = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", maxLength: 21, nullable: false),
        OnDelayMs = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: true),
        OffDelayMs = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: true)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_LayoutElements", x => x.Id);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_LayoutElements_Drawings_DrawingDataId",
            column: x => x.DrawingDataId,
            principalTable: "Drawings",
            principalColumn: "Id");
    });

The original intention of Adding both the new and old objects was, in my understanding, to make the DbManager aware of the objects; I didn't realize that Add meant Add in the simple insert-row sense.
My application has a list of objects, some of which may already be stored in the database and some which only exist in memory. The intention of my save-project function is to ensure the current state of all application objects are written to the database. Thus, I was just Adding all objects to ensure that the DbManager was aware of them.
One commenter seems to think using 'Update' is an indication of erroneous logic. How would you recommend modifying an object's fields in the database when the values have been modifying in-memory, other than using this function?
Of course I'm not trying to "convince" the DbManager that an object came from the database when it didn't. I'm trying to put my applications state into the database, where part of that state may previously have been loaded using a separate DbManager context, and part of the the state has been created in-memory since the last database write.

Here "create a new DbContext, and add both the original object (ID=1) and the new object (ID=0)": (1) the new DbContext is connected to the same database (2) You are using Add method to add the original object (ID=1) (3) Add means "create/insert new record" with ID=1 (4) on SaveChanges, the inserted record with ID=1 conflicts with the existing database record with ID=1. Do I miss something? The question should be why you are adding the object with ID=1 to the new context instead of loading it?

@IvanStoev does this mean I should be selective about which objects I Add? I was thinking Add was idempotent, but maybe I just imagined that. I thought Add mean Add the object to be tracked, and EF would decide whether to insert a new row or not.

@IvanStoev it seems I should have been using Update to re-attach the disconnected objects. After switching Add for Update it seems to be working the way I expected.

@afarley It's important to show the actual code. A description doesn't show the exact details that matter. For example, using Update may not be the best way to fix this error.

Also please show the CREATE TABLE definition

@afarley Add means always add new (a.k.a. create, insert). For autogenerated ids Update can be used for both update or insert (a.k.a. upsert). More info in official docs: Saving single entities and related

Tell us more about why you're doing add both the original object (ID = 1) - it seems to me you've come to some wrong conclusion about how EF should be used. I've never used Update in my life; if you're trying to convince EF that some object you got from elsewhere, is already in the database, in order to wrangle EF into treating it some way it's usually an indicator you've done something wrong/sub optimal somewhere else, like using your DB entities as your front end UI models
